# Why this code isn't replacing all uppercase into lowercase and all lowercase into uppercase letter?

Tags: kotlin

I thought that this code will change all uppercase into lowercase and lowercase into uppercase but it isn't working.. why?

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val userInput = readLine()!!
    val output = userInput 

    for(a in output){
        when{
            a.isUpperCase() -> a.toLowerCase()
            a.isLowerCase() -> a.toUpperCase()
            else -> a
        }
    }

    println(output)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fun changeCase(input : String) : String {
    val builder = StringBuilder()
    for (i in 0..input.length-1){
        val char : Char = input[i]
        if (char.isUpperCase) builder.append(char.toLowerCase)
        else if (char.isLowerCase) builder.append(char.toUpperCase)
        else builder.append(char)
    }
    return builder.toString()
}
```

In your code, you created an upper/lower-case character, but didn't assign it to the new output string. Methods dealing with String do not change an existing one but create a copy of it with the changed value!

Comment: Kotlin has `for (i in 0 until input.length)` to avoid the manual "-1". Since you don't need the index, I'd favour Kotlin's `String.forEach`, which gives you the chars directly: `input.forEach { ...add to builder... }`; the char is available via `it`. For me, it's more idiomatic to use map: `input.map { ...swap case... }.joinToString("")`